# File uploading using .net angular error coming like file is required even file is uploaded

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-webapi

I am trying to upload file using Angular and .Net, below is code which I have used.

I am getting error like file field is required, but I am uploading file but still getting error.

```
errors: {file: ["The file field is required."]}
file: ["The file field is required."]
status: 400
title: "One or more validation errors occurred."
type: "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1"
```

Below is .Net side code.

```
  [HttpPost("weeklyproductionreports/uploadfilesnew")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> UploadWeeklyProductionReportsFiles([FromForm] IFormFile file) =>
            Ok(await _companyService.UploadWeeklyProductionReportsFiles(file));
```

Below is Html code.

```
 <div class="myfilebrowser">
            <input type="file" #UploadFileInput id="fileUpload" (change)="fileChangeEvent($event)" name="fileUpload"
              multiple="multiple"
              accept="application/pdf,application/vnd.ms-excel,application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet" />
          </div>
```

Below is ts file code.

```
 fileChangeEvent(fileInput: any) {
    if (fileInput.target.files && fileInput.target.files[0]) {
      this.file = fileInput.target.files[0];
    }
  }

 upload() {
    this.isSubmitting = true;
    let formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('file', this.file, this.file.name);
    this.apiService.uploadWeeklyProductionReportFile(formData).subscribe(
      (data) => {
        this.isSubmitting = false;
        if (data.statusCode == 200) {
          console.log(data);
          this.uploadedFileUrl = data.data[0];
          this.snackBar.open('File uploaded!', 'Ok', {
            duration: 2000,
          });

          this.isShowFileUpload = true;
        } else {
          this.snackBar.open('File Upload Error: Please Try again', 'Ok', {
            duration: 2000,
          });
        }
      },
      (error) => {
        this.isSubmitting = false;
        console.log(error);
        this.snackBar.open('File Upload Error: Please Try again', 'Ok', {
          duration: 2000,
        });
      }
    );
    console.log('Upload works');
  }
```

below is API calling code.

```
uploadWeeklyProductionReportFile(body: FormData): Observable<any> {
    const url = this.baseURL + '/company/weeklyproductionreports/uploadfilesnew';
    return this.http.post<any>(url, body, { headers: { 'content-type': 'multipart/form-data' } });
  }
```

Comment: I deduce the issue happened when compose the form , could you pls see the form data in F12 when sending the request to your API? If the form had the property name `file` and the corresponding value is the file steam? By the way I think there're many samples for uploading file from Angular client to asp.net core api, such as [this](https://dotnetthoughts.net/upload-files-dot-net-core-angular). Could you pls take a look at it?

Answer (score 0):

So, I would start by changing your `upload()` method and adding an input parameter:

```
upload(files: Array<any>)
```

And where you append your form data I would do the following:

```
formData.append(files[0].name, files[0])
```